# how can i implement popup on leaflet wms layer from geoserver

Tags: popup, leaflet, geoserver

i want to display popup for a layer on my map this layer is from geoserver wms

```
map.addEventListener("click", onMapClick);
popup_layer= new L.Popup({maxwidth:700});
wms_server='http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms';


function onMapClick(e) {
 var BBOX=map.getBounds().toBBoxString();
 var WIDTH=map.getSize().x;
 var HEIGHT=map.getSize().y;
 var X=map.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.LayerPoint).x;
 var Y=map.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.LayerPoint).y;
 var URL=wms_server+'wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=abhbc%3Avw_ires&bbox='+BBOX+'&width=330&height=768&srs=EPSG%3A26191&format=application/openlayers';
 $.ajax({
    url: URL,
    datatype:"html",
    type:GET,
    success: function (data) {
       var popup= new L.popup({maxwidth:300})
       popup.setcontent(data)
       popup.setlatlng(e.latlng);
       map.openPopup(popup);
       },
    });
}
```

this is a code that i tried but it does not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate leaflet popup on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914166/populate-leaflet-popup-on-click)

Comment: it is not the same :(

Comment: why is it not the same?

Comment: sorry i thought it was rhe answer for another question because i have posted 2 questions in stack overflow

Comment: This question has the answer you are looking for: [Answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232789/disable-leaflet-wms-getfeatureinfo-popup-while-using-the-measure-tool)